# Is there any way to acess the google cloud shell persistent disk from datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I just want to go to the shell, clone a repository, go to datalab and work on that repository, pull it back and delete the instance.

In order to do that I need to access the repository that has been cloned in the persistent disk.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Datalab instance cannot access the disk that Cloud Shell uses, but here is a workaround you could try:

1. Create the Datalab instance.
2. From the Cloud Shell instance, copy your files to the Datalab instance using `gcloud compute copy-files`.
3. Work on the files inside of Datalab.
4. Go back to the Cloud Shell instance and use `gcloud compute copy-files` to pull the changed files back to your Cloud Shell instance.
5. Delete the Datalab instance.

However, the simplest option is going to be if you can clone the repository directly to the Datalab instance, work with it, and then push back to the repository directly from Datalab.

For GitHub repositories, the way I prefer to set this up is to generate an SSH keypair on my Datalab instance and then add it as a deploy key to my repository.

The code cell to run inside of my Datalab instance is:

```
%bash

export GIT_KEYFILE="/content/datalab/.ssh/id_rsa"
mkdir -p $(dirname ${GIT_KEYFILE})
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C `git config --global user.email` -P "" -f "${GIT_KEYFILE}"
echo "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cp ${GIT_KEYFILE}* ~/.ssh/ && ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts" >> /content/datalab/.config/startup.sh
mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cp ${GIT_KEYFILE}* ~/.ssh/ && ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

echo $'\nProvide the following to GitHub as your deploy key:'
cat "${GIT_KEYFILE}.pub"
```

That both generates the key and ensures that git is configured properly on Datalab startup to use that key.

The bit you would need to copy and paste into GitHub as the deploy key is in the output of the code cell starting with "ssh-rsa" and ending with your email address.

Comment: Thank you Omar. I ended up using the SDK following this tutorial:                          https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/02/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-jupyter-notebooks-with-apache-spark-on-google-cloud